# Como retornar o último elemento do array usando o metodo for?

Tags: javascript, for

Eu queria saber como eu pego o ultimo elemento do *array* usando a estrutura `for` no caso para decremento?

O meu código é esse:

```js
const a = n => n % 2 === 0;
function callbackfn (valorInserido, funcao) {
  for (valorInserido.length; i=0; i--) {
    if (funcao(valorInserido[i])) {
      return valorInserido[i];
    }
  }
}
console.log(callbackfn([3,5,2,4],(a)));
```

No caso era pra retornar o número `4`, porém retorna `undefined`.

Comment: Este código tem erros de sintaxe e não parece fazer o que está descrito na pergunta. Pode esclarecer?

Comment: @Maniero ele é um código que tem a mesma função do `find` porém, eu quero fazer um `findLast` e não estou conseguindo.

Apenas quero fazer ele pega o ultimo valor que retorna true.

o `find`pega o primeiro valor que retorna true, eu quero pegar o ultimo.

Comment: Não precisa de `for` usa `array[array.length - 1]` que vai retornar o ultimo elemento

Comment: @PedroPinto ele quer condicionalmente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código tem vários erros.

Não está inicializado a variável `i` e tem que inicializar com o número de elementos menos 1, já que começa do zero. A condição de termino do laço deveria ser enquanto `i` for maior ou igual a 0. Se pergunta se é igual a 0, nunca será, a não ser que o *array* não tenha elementos, o que não importa. E na verdade se fosse igual, seria o `==`, o `=` é atribuição.

Melhorei o estilo.

```js
const condicao = n => n % 2 === 0;
function PegaUltimoCondicionalmente(valorInserido, funcao) {
  for (var i = valorInserido.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (funcao(valorInserido[i])) return valorInserido[i];
}
console.log(PegaUltimoCondicionalmente([3, 5, 2, 4], condicao));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/FilterLast.js).

Comment: Caraca, obrigado, <3

Comment: No caso, nem é o último propriamente, é o último par. :)

Comment: Uma duvida, o código `var i = valorInserido.length - 1`, esse -1 faz ele descer uma posição? Ou ele inverte o array ?

Comment: ele subtrai um, nada mais que isto. Sabe matemática? faz a conta.